# Search on Mongo DB ISODate is not fetching any record using java

Tags: java, mongodb, date, database

I have tried different ways to find the data with query on date range, but none of it seems to work. I have gone through all the questions posted on StackOverflow as well.

```
DBCollection findCollection = getMongoUtil().findCollection(collectionName);


// 1st method

BasicDBObject query = new BasicDBObject("createDate", new BasicDBObject("$gt", analyticsSearch.getjStartDate()).append("$lte", analyticsSearch.getjEndDate()));

// 2nd method

query.put("createDate", new BasicDBObject("$gt",new DateTime(analyticsSearch.getjStartDate().getTime())).append("$lte", new DateTime(analyticsSearch.getjEndDate().getTime())));

// 3rd method

query.put("createDate", new BasicDBObject("$gt",analyticsSearch.getjStartDate()).append("$lte", analyticsSearch.getjEndDate()));


// 4th method

QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();
qb.put("createDate").greaterThan(analyticsSearch.getjStartDate()).lessThan(analyticsSearch.getjEndDate());
BasicDBObject bdo = new BasicDBObject();
bdo.putAll(qb.get());
DBCursor find = findCollection.find(bdo);
```

The query which is constructed is of the form

```
query={ "createDate" : { "$gt" : { "$date" : "2014-11-30T18:30:00.000Z"} , "$lte" : { "$date" : "2015-06-03T17:30:00.000Z"}}}
```

While the collection holds the data in this format :

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("556da50944ae75266d15adb0"),
"createDate" : ISODate("2015-06-02T12:43:53.286Z"),
"name" : "xyz",
"company" : "abc"
}
```

I guess, Query consists of $date which is breaking it. Please suggest how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a standard Java date object

Assuming analyticsSearch.getjStartDate() and analyticsSearch.getjEndDate() are java.util.Date objects, try this:

```
query.put("createDate", new BasicDBObject("$gt",analyticsSearch.getjStartDate())).append("$lte", analyticsSearch.getjEndDate())));
```

Sorry I haven't change all your examples :-)

Tested against local setup with the following code and it worked as expected

```
    MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
    DB db = mongoClient.getDB("mydb");
    QueryBuilder qb = new QueryBuilder();
    Calendar scal = Calendar.getInstance();
    scal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    scal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    scal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
    scal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 11);
    scal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    scal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    scal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 114);
    Calendar ecal = Calendar.getInstance();
    ecal.set(Calendar.YEAR, 2015);
    ecal.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
    ecal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 20);
    ecal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    ecal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 15);
    ecal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 20);
    ecal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 114);

    qb.put("date").greaterThan(scal.getTime()).lessThan(ecal.getTime());

    BasicDBObject bdo = new BasicDBObject();
    bdo.putAll(qb.get());
    DBCollection findCollection = db.getCollection("mycoll");
    DBCursor find = findCollection.find(bdo);

    System.out.println(scal.getTime());
    System.out.println(ecal.getTime());
    System.out.println(find.count());
```

There are 12329 documents in mycoll. The count for this query is 65.

Comment: yes, analyticsSearch.getjStartDate() and analyticsSearch.getjEndDate() are java.util.Date objects, sorry for the confusion. already tried the solution given by you in the 1st method. But it didn't work. Please see whether anything is wrongly done by me.

Comment: Just updated my answer with a test I created to show that Java dates work. I hope it helps.